# Installing a Nest thermostat without a C wire?

Tags: hvac, thermostat-c-wire, nest

[image]I am attempting to install a nest but do not have a common wire on my hvac unit, perhaps it is slightly dated. I have read that on older units the O terminal is the same as C and I can remove the green wire (fan) and use that on my O as my common wire. Since I am unable to add a net new wire, could someone kindly let me know if this is a viable solution and the best approach I should take (see pic of my setup)? Thank you.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It seems that your photo did not post...try hitting "edit" in the "share edit...." links on the bottom left, then using the mountain-and-sun button in the editor to upload your photo

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: What make and model is your furnace/air-handler?

Comment: Goodman. Model #GMNTE080-4 (03100004307). Thanks @ThreePhaseEel

Answer (score 1):

### Try the terminal between G and Y on your control board

It looks like the C terminal on your control board is between the G and Y terminals, so I would try there as your first port of call, provided your thermostat cable has spare wires in it.  (It's labeled /C in the bottom row of labels, and has a wire from what likely is your air conditioner compressor running to it already.)

Comment: How did I miss that - I took a closer look and it is B/C. I guess I was looking for a standalone C.  I don’t have any spare wires so do I move my green over and connect it to that B/C terminal? Thanks

Comment: @MatthewMcKenzie -- we thank people around here by upvoting and/or accepting their answers :)

Comment: ThreePhaseEel or anyone else, I just read that if I use my G as my C since I don’t have any extra wires in my harness I should or need to fix a jump wire between my Y and G on the furnace.  Thoughts?  Thank you very much

Comment: @MatthewMcKenzie -- yeah, if you do that, you need to jumper Y to G so that the furnace blower runs during cooling

Comment: Hi ThreePhaseEel - Just moved the green over to B/C and added a jumper between Y and G.  Could you please take a look at the first pic I just posted and let me know if all checks out? I turned everything on and sounded like everything fired back up without issue.  Thanks again.

Comment: @MatthewMcKenzie -- just make sure it works in both heat and cool :) and don't forget to upvote/accept my answer

Comment: Thanks. Works for heat but can’t test cold until outside gets above 16c. I think I figured out how to upvote.  Thanks again.